# Creating Burn-Earn credits mapping

Tags: sql, python-3.x, postgresql

I have two tables where for every user earned credits and burned credits are logged. Based on user's purchase loyalty points (credits) are given which are saved in "earned_credits" table. And he can redeem it in next purchases (this data is saved in "burned_credits" table)

I need to find the mapping (relation) for each "burned_credits" transaction with entry in "earned_credits" table

The table structure for earned_credits include:

```
id | user_id | credits_earned | earn_id | created_at | valid_upto
```

The table structure for burned_credits include:

```
id | user_id | credits_burned | burn_id | created_at
```

The relation between burn_id and earn_id needs to be defined. I tried using loop function in python where earned_credits.valid_upto < burned_credits.created_at and sum(earned_credits.credits_earned) - sum(burned_credits.credits_burned) >= 0 but the logic is failing at point where partial credits are burned.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @jarlh PostgreSQL is being used by the system